# How use jquery npm in node.js ?

Tags: node.js

for example i want use jquery function extend

```
var object = $.extend({}, object1, object2);
```

But :

```
 var $ = require('jquery');
```

console : 
**$**

```
function ( w ) {
                if ( !w.document ) {
                    throw new Error( "jQuery requires a window with a doc…
```

**$.extend** undefined

Comment: What's your version of jQuery? And I quote from https://www.npmjs.org/package/jquery: "To use jQuery in Node, browser extensions, and other non-browser environments, use only 2.x releases. 1.x does not support these environments."

Comment: Also please write out the full error message clearly, this will help get us to an answer

Comment: For reference sake the full error message was: "jQuery requires a window with a document"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jquery is only for client side. For server side (node.js0, it used for unitTest scripting with browserify, ... because node.js has no window, document and DOM layer.
I recommand you to use underscore.js :

```
npm install underscore
```

Underscore.js has a `extend` method works like jquery.extend. :

```
var _ = require('underscore');
var obj = _.extend({}, object1, object2);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get this to work but you'll need another module called `jsdom` because jQuery **needs** a DOM window to operate, it's not designed for Node.js. Install it with:

```
npm install jsdom --save
```

*Please note: I'm using the latest jQuery 2.1.1 and jsdom 1.0.0-pre.6 both installed via npm*

And then in your Node.js file e.g. `app.js`:

```
var jsdom = require('jsdom'),
    window = jsdom.jsdom().parentWindow,
    $ = require('jquery')(window);

var object = $.extend({},{'foo':'bar'},{'cat':'dog'});
console.log(object);
```

Then in Node.js you run it:

```
node app.js
```

And see the output:

```
{ foo: 'bar', cat: 'dog' }
```

Perhaps the better option is to use something like [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) which is a "fast, flexible, and lean implementation of core jQuery designed specifically for the server". You can install this with `npm install cheerio`.